# Running multiple jobs at a time on GCML

Tags: billing, google-cloud-ml

I had tried running multiple jobs on Google Cloud ML some time back. And it had failed with an error on the lines of "Allowe number of instances exceed".  However, when I tried it again I was able to run multiple training jobs at once.
How is the price for this calculated ?
Is there a way/(NEED) to queue an ML training/retraining job if another is already running, considering it uses the same project for both?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud ML's pricing is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml/pricing). Quotas are described [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml/quotas). Every Cloud ML job uses up so many ML units depending on the job's tier. There's a [limit](https://cloud.google.com/ml/quotas#limits_on_cuncurrent_ml_training_units) to how many ML units can be consumed concurrently for a project. You can increase this quota if you need to be able to run more jobs simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Server-side queuing in Cloud ML for jobs does not exist as of now.

If your jobs need more ML units than what your quota allows, you either need to increase you quota or you need to implement queuing on your side.